# boost shared pointer constructor destructor

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

The following code

```
struct Base
{
  public:
  Base()
  {
    std::cout<<"Base Ctr";
  }

  ~Base()
  {
    std::cout<<"Base Dtr";
  }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  Derived()
  {
    std::cout<<"Derived Ctr";
  }

  ~Base()
  {
    std::cout<<"Derived Dtr";
  }
};

int main()
{
  Base* b = new Derived;
  delete b;
}
```

gives me the following output :

```
Base Ctr
Derived Ctr
Base Dtr
```

The solution to this is to make the base destructor virtual.

However when I use boost smart pointers without virtual base destructor. I get a different output.

```
int main()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<Base> b = boost::make_shared<Derived>();
}
```

The output is

```
 Base Ctr
 Derived Ctr
 Derived Dtr
 Base Dtr
```

How is boost shared_ptr able to achieve this without affecting(I'm assuming) the Base and Derived classes.
How does it scale it for multiple level inheritance, i.e base points to dervderv
where dervderv is inherited from derv.

EDIT:

Most answers tell me that the "magic" happens in make_shared. I however get the same behaviour for the following code

```
boost::shared_ptr<Base> ptr(new Derived);
```

Comment: your classes don't have virtual destructors. isn't this undefined behavior?

Comment: Exactly the point I'm trying to figure out. This behaviour is not defined in case of boost smart pointers

Comment: @PranavKapoor you can modify my example by adding another constructor to pointer class:  template <typename Y>
 explicit pointer(Y* p) : p_(p), deleter_(std::bind(&default_deleter<Y>, p)) {}

Comment: @PranavKapoor if you understand that it's UB, then why are you even trying to reason about it?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant : it's not undefined behavior. It's the way `boost::shared_ptr` is implemented.

Comment: @PranavKapoor : re. your edit - the "magic" is not a property of `make_shared`, but of `shared_ptr` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution implemented using normal function pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct Base{

  Base(){
    cout<<"Base ctor."<<endl;
  }

  ~Base(){
    cout<<"Base dtor."<<endl;
  }

};

struct Derv: Base{

  Derv():Base(){
    cout<<"Derv ctor."<<endl;
  }

  ~Derv(){
    cout<<"Derv dtor."<<endl;
  }

};

typedef void (*DEL)(void*);

template<typename U>
void deleter(void* ptr)
{
  delete static_cast<U*>(ptr);
}

template<typename T>
struct SmartPtr{

  T* memPtr;

  DEL func;

  template<typename U>
    SmartPtr(U* p):
      memPtr(p)
  {
    func = deleter<U>;
  }

  ~SmartPtr(){

      func(memPtr);
  }
};
int main()
{
  //case 1
  SmartPtr<Base> ptrSmart1(new Derv());

  //case 2
  SmartPtr<Base> ptrSmart2(new Base());

  //case 3
  SmartPtr<Derv> ptrSmart3(new Derv());

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In brief, `boost::smart_ptr` contains pointer to an object, reference count and a deleter function, which is called in destructor, when you call `boost::make_shared<Derived>()`, it will create default-constructed object of class `Derived` and deleter will point to a destructor of `Derived`. This should work for inheritance chain of any length, but having virtual destructor in the base class is really mandatory.

Consider next simplified naive example implementation of such technique:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct Base
{
  public:
  Base()
  {
    std::cout<<"Base Ctr ";
  }

  ~Base()
  {
    std::cout<<"Base Dtr ";
  }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  Derived()
  {
    std::cout<<"Derived Ctr ";
  }

  Derived(const Derived& d)
  {
    std::cout<<"Derived copy Ctr ";
  }

  ~Derived()
  {
    std::cout<<"Derived Dtr ";
  }
};

template <typename T>
void default_deleter(T* p) {
    delete p;
}

template <typename T>
struct pointer {
    pointer(T* p, std::function<void ()> d) : p_(p), deleter_(d) {}
    template <typename U>
    pointer(pointer<U> other) : p_(new U(*other.p_)), 
    deleter_(std::bind(&default_deleter<U>, (U*)p_)) {}
    template <typename Y>
    explicit pointer(Y* p) : p_(p), deleter_(std::bind(&default_deleter<Y>, p)) {}
    ~pointer() {
        deleter_();
    }
    T* p_;
    std::function<void ()> deleter_;
};


template <typename T>
pointer<T> make_pointer() {
    T* p = new T;
    return pointer<T>(p, std::bind(&default_deleter<T>, p));
}

int main() {
    pointer<Base> b = make_pointer<Derived>();
    pointer<Base> b2(new Derived);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Base Ctr Derived Ctr Base Ctr Derived copy Ctr Derived Dtr Base Dtr Derived Dtr Base Dtr
```

destructors of Derived class are called twice because there are 2 instances of pointer : one which was created in make_pointer function and the second is in main function.

Comment: as per your output dtr's are called twice, can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

Boost achieves that by having a deleter functor. The default implementation calls `delete` on the type created using `make_shared`.

Comment: a good article on the subject : https://marcoarena.wordpress.com/2014/04/12/ponder-the-use-of-unique_ptr-to-enforce-the-rule-of-zero/